# Ruby on Rails app on Heroku crashes on startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, sqlite3-ruby

The app works fine in local host, and also uploads to Heroku just fine. The crash error is ":in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem': Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile. (LoadError)" Here's the full error:

```
2019-10-26T21:11:00.461852+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 21484 -e production`
2019-10-26T21:11:04.328605+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-10-26T21:11:04.357692+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-10-26T21:11:04.27043+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:406:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem': Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile. (LoadError)
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270452+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270454+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270456+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270457+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270461+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270462+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270465+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270466+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270469+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270472+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:191:in `spec'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270475+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:956:in `establish_connection'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270478+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:60:in `establish_connection'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270481+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:136:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270483+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `instance_eval'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270486+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270489+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270492+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270494+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270497+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.2705+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270502+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:328:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270505+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270507+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.27051+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270513+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270516+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270518+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270521+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270524+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270527+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.27053+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.3/app/models/active_storage/attachment.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270533+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270536+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270539+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270542+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270545+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270548+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270551+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270554+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270557+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:378:in `block in require_or_load'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.27056+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270563+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270569+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270575+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270576+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270579+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:356:in `require_or_load'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270581+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:48:in `block in require_or_load'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270582+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270584+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:47:in `require_or_load'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270586+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:334:in `depend_on'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270588+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:85:in `depend_on'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270591+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:246:in `require_dependency'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270592+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:478:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2019-10-26T21:11:04.270595+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:477:in `each'
```

However, I went through the process outlined in [getting started with rails5](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5), and have PG specified in both my development and production environments in the database.yml files. Here is my database.yml file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/pg_development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/pg_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/pg_production
```

The app works in development, but crashes when I try to open it in Heroku. It deploys to Heroku fine. I've been scratching my head over this, especially since it's not the first time I've deployed a Rails app to Heroku - any help would be very appreciated!

Here's my Gemfile in case it is a dependency issue:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use bootstrap
gem 'bootstrap'
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you checked your `Gemfile.lock`?

Comment: Whats going on with `database: db/pg_test` etc? Thats a really strange way to name your databases. You can also remove `database: db/pg_production` as Heroku uses `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` to configure the production database anyways.

Comment: @max I'm still fairly new to most of this, including the DB naming conventions, and I've successfully set up a rails pg app with this in the past. I'll try reconfiguring the production database using an ENV variable it see if that helps. Thanks.

Comment: @jvillian What am I looking for in my Gemfile.lock?

Comment: Usually you would name the dbs something like 'myapp_test' . You shouldn't have to do anything at all on heroku. It sets the env var to point to the attached db automatically as soon as you push a rails app. This error could also be caused by db/schema.rb if you have generated it with sqlite.

Comment: A reference to `sqlite3`. You *could* try deleting `Gemfile.lock` and then running `bundle update` - which will cause `Gemfile.lock` to be re-created.

Comment: @jvillian No references to sqlite3 in my Gemfile.lock, but deleted it and recreated it anything. No change.

Comment: @max I was using sqlite briefly, so that might be my problem - how do I reset the db/schema?

Comment: Hmm, try deleting schema.rb and running rails db:migrate

Comment: @max Solved it! In the DB folder there were some files named test.sqlite3 and development.sqlite3. Deleting those seemed to have fixed the problem. Thanks for all your help!